# Serving index.html from a subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, lamp

In my document root, I have to directories: `home` and `foobar`, both with their own index.html files.

How can I set it up so that when someone visits my site at `example.com`, they see the contents on `home/index.html`?

I tried using an `index.php` with a redirect in document root, as well as a `.htaccess` redirect, but both of them change the URL in the browser to `example.com/home/`, which I would like to ideally avoid.

Comment: If you need the 'big gun': [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
First check if requested file is present. If it is, return it. If not, rewrite to '/home'. Sorry no code example at hand right now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just move the contents of `home` up one directory?

Comment: Because the contents of each directory in my document-root belong to a different git repo. Having the contents of home up one level will cause me to commit other projects (in the wrong repo) as well when I commit the contents of home.

Comment: If they are inteded to work together, you can actually put one in the other using [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Answer (score 0):

What about the simplest solution: Creating a simple PHP file that includes the document?

```
<?php
   include("html/index.html");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions to your problem.

## 1. Using virtual hosts

You probably have a VirtualHost that points to your website. Edit it this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/directory/home # add /home at the end
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory /path/to/your/directory>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then don't forget to restart apache2 (or httpd)

## 2. Using `.htaccess`

Add this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home/$1
```

Note that `/foobar` will be completely impossible to reach exept by an `include` from your `/home` directory.